# how to refer a newly created column in withColumn and check for null

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to do this, but I get error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'isNull'`

```
table_df_flat \
            .withColumn("test",f.lit(None)) \
            .withColumn("yes",f.when("test".isNull(),"yes")) \
```

It could work if I try this but I get this error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'test'`

```
table_df_flat \
            .withColumn("test",f.lit(None)) \
            .withColumn("yes",f.when(table_df_flat.test.isNull(),"yes")) \
```

How to fix to use it in the same query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use col and then check if this is null

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

table_df_flat = spark.createDataFrame([("test",)], ["favorites"])

table_df_flat.withColumn("test", F.lit(None)).withColumn(
    "yes", F.when(F.col("test").isNull(), "yes")
).show()
```